# I need to imitate the finger touch, draw the imprint of the touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, fingerprint

i want to let the user touch the screen and i take these touches size and location and provide him with an image "as if it" was his fingerprint but with almost the same shape and size of his finger

i implemented the touchesBegan Function and the touchesMoves Function as follows (both have the same code)

as it's shown below the touchSize is the size of the actual user touch to the screen and it holds the radius of the touch, then i created a circular shape using SKshapeNode and color and displayed it on screen

it colors the node where i touched but when i move a touch the size starts to get bigger and i can not get it to draw the shape of the finger

```
        -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins*/

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
CGFloat touchSize = [[touch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
        SKShapeNode *touchedLocation = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:touchSize/4];
        touchedLocation.fillColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        touchedLocation.position = location;
        [self addChild:touchedLocation];
}
```

}

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self]; 
CGFloat touchSize = [[touch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
        isScreenTouched = YES;
        SKShapeNode *touchedLocation = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:touchSize/4];
        touchedLocation.fillColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        touchedLocation.position = location;
        touchedLocation.name = @"AnamelPrint";
        [self addChild:touchedLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Little confusing... if you just want an imprint of the finger, why are you using touchesMoved?

Comment: well i'm a beginner in iOS. i used touchesMoved because when i only use touchesBegan it shows a small circular shape and i want it to be in the shape of finger

Comment: You do realize that the screen cannot actually "read" a finger print. I suggest you take an image of a finger print and place it on the touch location to simulate what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes i'm very aware of that thank you :) and i'm not trying to take a fingerprint of the user. i'm trying to draw the shape of the imprint

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much spot on but I suggest you change this line of code:

```
SKShapeNode *touchedLocation = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:touchSize/4];
```

to this:

```
SKShapeNode *touchedLocation = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:touchSize];
```

That will give you the right size based on the touch radius. Also, from what I understand you are trying to do, you do not need to have anything in the touchesMoved method. Unless you want to keep drawing circles while the finger is being moved.